# Apache2 - Rewriting when using reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

## Background

I want to set up utorrent with webui on my server.

## Problem

Utorrent sets up its own webserver which, by default, listens on port 8080.

The ui is then accessed by accessing example.com:8080/gui

My goal is to have subdomain.server.com using reverse proxy.
The problem comes when I discovered that some urls are hard coded to /gui/* which of course breaks things.

I'm now trying to remove that initial /gui from the request using mod rewrite but for some reason it's not working.

I can access the site (I get the utorrent loading screen) but if I check my log I see that all requests to `/gui/token.html` get a 404 Not Found response, `/token.html` works just fine if I try it manually though.

I've tried moving the rewrite to the proxy but that doesn't work either.

## What I have so far

Here is my virtual host file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteRule ^/gui(/?)(.*)$ /$2

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/utorrent-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/utorrent-access.log common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/*.domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/*.domain.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain-ca-ssl.crt

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>

<proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    AuthName subdomain.example.com
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/utorrent/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as adding the [PT] flag to the rewrite

Answer (score -1):

Worked like a charm with the PT switch added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName utorrent.yourdomain.com
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RewriteEngine  on
        RewriteRule ^/gui(/?)(.*)$ /$2 [PT]
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/   
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/gui/   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Doesn't differ a single bit from the accepted answer. What gives?